# What is the correct equation for Newton's Method?

Tags: algorithms, numerics

Different publications provide different equations for Newton's method or the Newton-Raphson method. In

Giudici, P., Givens, G. H., & Mallick, B. K. (2013). Wiley Series in Computational Statistics. Wiley Online Library, p. 26

the updating equation is given as

$$
x^{(t+1)}=x^{(t)}-\frac{g^{\prime}\left(x^{(t)}\right)}{g^{\prime \prime}\left(x^{(t)}\right)}
$$

whereas elsewhere on the internet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method),

it is given as

$$
x^{(t+1)}=x^{(t)}-\frac{g\left(x^{(t)}\right)}{g^{\prime}\left(x^{(t)}\right)}
$$

Are these equivalent? How can I make sense of the difference?

Comment: Are you using optimization to find a zero of $g$ or a zero of $g^\prime$?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure. The application is for univariate MLE, so the goal is to estimate a parameter. But then, I'm wondering if it shouldn't always be the same algorithm to estimate the maximum likelihood?

Comment: The goal of MLE is to find the *maximum* of the likelihood; maxima and maxima occur when the first derivative is 0. The first update rule finds *roots* of $g$, values $x$ where $g(x)=0$. The second update rule finds *extrema* of $g$, values $x$ where $g^\prime(x)=0$.

Comment: See also the wikipedia page on the method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Minimization_and_maximization_problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Both are correct.

Which one you should use depends on what problem you're trying to solve.

- The first update rule finds *roots* of $g$, values $x$ where $g(x)=0$.
- The second update rule finds *extrema* of $g$, values $x$ where $g^\prime(x)=0$.

This is simple enough to demonstrate. Suppose that the function we wish to optimize is $f = g^\prime$. If we plug $f$ into the first equation, we are finding zeros of $f$. If we replace $f$ with $g^\prime$, then we recover the second equation.

Comment: Which one would you use in the context of MLE? What are common use cases for both in statistics?

Comment: Suppose your maximizing a function $f(x)$. The function is maximized at $x^*$. What's the value of $f^\prime (x^*)$?